# How to plot this function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I want to plot functions (using some software, any recommendations?) that looks like this below. Could someone suggest equations of functions that would look like the graph below? 
[image: 123]

Comment: There are many of them: I have started to use Geogebra.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me an example?

Comment: Have you tried: gnuplot (free), mathematica, matlab, ...? The functions you list could be more or less anything - how about $b(x) = (x/10)^2, h(x) = 1+b(x), g(x) = 2+b(x), f(x) = 3+b(x)$?

Answer (score 4):

Besides the excellent suggestions made by Johannes Kloos

> Have you tried: gnuplot (free), mathematica, matlab, ...? The functions you list could be more or less anything - how about $b(x)=(x/10)^2$, $h(x)=1+b(x)$, $g(x)=2+b(x)$, $f(x)=3+b(x)$?

I'll add that [fooplot](http://fooplot.com/plot/2zkbmzpk7e) is free, runs in a browser, and is very easy to use:

[image: fooplot example]

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the plots by using MAPLE as follows:

```
[> with(plots):
[> b := proc (x) options operator, arrow; (1/100)*x^2 end proc:
[> multiple(plot, [b(x), x = 0 .. 10, y = 0 .. 5,color and 0 .. 5,color = red, thickness = 3], [b(x)+1, x = 0 .. 10, y = 0 .. 5, color = green, thickness = 3], [b(x)+2, x = 0 .. 10, y = 0 .. 5, color = blue, thickness = 3], [b(x)+3, x = 0 .. 10, y = 0 .. 5, color = black, thickness = 3]);
```

[image]

Comment: @amWhy: Yes I wish I could go. Thanks, I am well but exhausted cause of 8 hours teaching. :-)

Comment: @amWhy: Honestly, I am addicted to be here Amy. Thanks for your supporting and warming words my dearest friend. ;-)